# Java - NotSerializableException on custom class

Tags: java, ioexception

I have this code (sorry if I use some terms in Spanish) in Java. All is OK, until I need to write an object in a file with `ObjectOutputStream`, when `printStackTrace` says `java.io.NotSerializableException`.

The code is this.

```
package agenda;
import java.io.*;

public class Agenda implements java.io.Serializable {

    public static void addContact() {

        String nom, ap1, ap2, tf, em;

        Contact newContact = new Contact("Nombre", "Apellido", "Apellido 2", "Telefono", "Email");

        try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("agenda.pzs", true)) {
            oos.writeObject(newContact); // NetBeans says the error is here

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace(); // This is provisional only
            System.out.println("Ocurrió un error inesperado.");
        } 
    }
```

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: What does the `Contact` class look like? Does it implement `Serializable`?

Comment: post your `Contact` class code, it should implement `Serializable` interface.

Comment: This code won't compile. The brackets are off. Or it's missing some pieces.

Comment: @AngeloAlvisi I took the liberty of assuming the OP's code compiles and fixed it, without changing the nature of the question.

Comment: Problem fixed. `Contact` class needs implement `Serializable` but I don't knew it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Agenda implements java.io.Serializable {

    public static void addContact() {

    String nom, ap1, ap2, tf, em;

    Contact newContact = new Contact("Nombre", "Apellido", "Apellido 2", "Telefono", "Email");

    try {
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("agenda.txt",true));
            oos.writeObject(newContact);
            oos.close();            

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(); 
        System.out.println("Ocurrió un error inesperado.");
    } 

    }
}
```

There is mistake with your bracket

and implement Serializable interface in Contact class

Answer (score 0):

All objects inside Serializable class must be Serializable. this requirement is traversable - all objects below must be Serializable too..

BUT...
Assuming that Contact is a third party class or you are not allowed to modify it for any other reason, here is possible solution:

DISCLAIMER: this is tricky, if you don't know "Contact" class well it may cause many unexpected issues. You must make sure that you are able to read/write state of "Contact" class using Serializable blocks. Any change in Contact implementation must be tracked. You need a set of JUnit tests to verify if wrapper is correct.

Now get to the point:
Create ContactWrapper class that will disassemble "Contact" class to serializable class on write() and assemble this class from blocks during read(). More or less something like this:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.io.*;

import org.junit.Test;

public class Agenda {

@Test
public void addContact() throws ClassNotFoundException, FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    String nom, ap1, ap2, tf, em;

     Contact newContact = new Contact("Nombre", "Apellido", "Apellido 2", "Telefono", "Email");

     ContactWrapper wrapper = new ContactWrapper();
     wrapper.setContact(newContact);

     ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
    try {
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("agenda.pzs"));
        oos.writeObject(wrapper);
    } finally{
       if(oos != null){ 
           oos.close();
       }
    }

    ObjectInputStream ois =  null;
    ContactWrapper wrapper_new = null;
    try{
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("agenda.pzs"));
        wrapper_new = (ContactWrapper) ois.readObject();
    } finally {
        if(ois != null)
            ois.close();
    }
    assertTrue(wrapper.equals(wrapper_new));

    Contact deserializedContact = wrapper.getContact();
    //Assuming that contact has corectly implemented equals()...
    assertTrue(newContact.equals(deserializedContact));

}
}
```

================================================

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectStreamException;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class ContactWrapper implements Serializable{
//assume not nulls here...-->equals
private String nom, ap1, ap2, tf, em;

public ContactWrapper(){

}

public void setContact(Contact contact){
  //Get State of "Contact" and write it to Serializable objects
  nom = contact.getNom();
  ap1 = contact.getAp1();
  //etc....
}

public Contact getContact(){
    //create Contact from serialized objects
    return new Contact(nom, ap1, ap2, tf, em);
}

private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out)
        throws IOException{
    System.out.println("write");
    out.writeObject(nom);
    out.writeObject(ap1);
    out.writeObject(ap2);
    out.writeObject(tf);
    out.writeObject(em);

}

    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in)
        throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
        System.out.println("read");   
        nom = (String) in.readObject();
        ap1 = (String) in.readObject();
        ap2 = (String) in.readObject();
        tf = (String) in.readObject();
        em = (String) in.readObject();

    }

    private void readObjectNoData()
        throws ObjectStreamException{
        System.out.println("readNoData");
        //set everything to null?
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if(this == other) return true;
        if(other instanceof ContactWrapper){
            ContactWrapper that = (ContactWrapper)other;
            if(this.nom.equals(that.nom) &&
                    this.ap1.equals(that.ap1)
                    //...etc etc
                    ){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Edit:
Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html